# make text different color when visitor is at specific classes on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a sidebar menu (plain html) to navigate at a page. For example:

```
<div class="sidebar"><h2>About us</h2>

<h3><a href="#chapter1" class="link">Chapter 1</a></h3>
<h3><a href="#chapter2" class="link">Chapter 2</a></h3>
<h3><a href="#chapter3"  class="link">Chapter 3</a></h3>
</div>
```

When a visitor clicks on Chapter 1, he goes to the Chapter 1 section and the Chapter 1 link in the sidebar is a different color for a few seconds (because of a:active delay).

However, this is not the solution for my case. I'm looking to make the link in the sidebar a different color when the visitor is at the Chapter 1 section.
When the visitor scrolls down to Chapter 2, Chapter 1 link will return normal and Chapter 2 link in the sidebar will be a different color.

Solutions/suggestions are welcome!

Update: I'm using Wordpress for this website.
There were some great suggestions, but it looks like they don't work for me. I'm using a Wordpress based website, and the sidebar is a Wordpress sidebar. 
The sidebar has a fixed position.

Comment: You will need to use javascript for this - a plugin like scrollspy (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) should work.

Comment: looks like all the links have **fixed** position? so when scrolling down, user can still sees the links (and of course click them)?

Comment: The solutions provided below work. implementing them to a live site won't work with a copy/paste action. You will need to make changes to the solutions and/or to your website so that they work for you. If you provide a fiddle or other with the HTML/CSS output of your website maybe we can help you adapt below solutions to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add styles for active or inactive

```
.active { color=red; }
.inactive { color=black; }
```

for your chapters, add onMouseOver="setActive(1)",  onMouseOver="setActive(2)",, etc...

Then add a js function to set the colors in the sidebar.

```
function setActive(ch)
{
   document.getElementById("#chapter1").className="link "+(ch==1:"active";"inactive");
   document.getElementById("#chapter2").className="link "+(ch==2:"active";"inactive");
   document.getElementById("#chapter3").className="link "+(ch==3:"active";"inactive");
}
```

You will probably also want to call setActive(xx) when you ckick on any of the sidebar elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is scrollspy.

Links:

- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy
- http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy

Comment: It looks like this would solve the issue easily. The website is a Wordpress based website, and it looks like this solution is in particular for Twitter Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has this built-in so you can use their breadcrumbs,

or I put together a nice fiddle that does this with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/8S2eu/2/

Here's the pertinent script:

#### Set up the page like so:

```
<div class="sidebar"><h2>About us</h2>

<h3><a href="#chapter1" class="link active" id="chapter1">Chapter 1</a></h3>
<h3><a href="#chapter2" class="link" id="chapter2">Chapter 2</a></h3>
<h3><a href="#chapter3"  class="link" id="chapter3">Chapter 3</a></h3>
</div>
<div class='main'>
    <section id="chapter1">
        <a id="chapter1"></a>
    </section>
    <section id="chapter2">
        <a id="chapter2"></a>
    </section>
    <section id="chapter3">
        <a id="chapter3"></a>
    </section>
</div>
```

#### And the necessary JS to run it:

```
$(".main").on("scroll",function(e){
    var fifty_percent_y = $(".main").height() * 0.5;
    var scroll_position = $(this).scrollTop();
    var prev_scroll_position = $(this).data('scroll_position');
    var delta = scroll_position - prev_scroll_position;
    $(this).data('scroll_position', scroll_position);


    //the rule is: if the top of chapter section tag crosses up across 50% then it becomes active, or if the bottom of a section tag crosses down across 50% then it becomes active.
    $('section').each(function(i, el){
        $this = $(this);
        var top_y = $this.position().top;
        var bottom_y = top_y + $this.height();
        if ((top_y     < fifty_percent_y && top_y    + delta > fifty_percent_y) ||
            (bottom_y  > fifty_percent_y && bottom_y + delta < fifty_percent_y)
           ){
            $("a").removeClass('active');
            $("a#" + $this[0].id).addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution, and it looks like it didn't work because the sidebar and the content of my page were not seen as the same page. (Using Wordpress).

Comment: Do you mean they're in different frames? That you're using wordpress (a back-end cms/framework) is irrelevant for a front-end problem like this.